# Only first part of Javascript function being called

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax

I'm having problems with this function I've made, the first part is called fine but after the first if statements nothing else is being called. I've used JSfiddle, but it doesn't indentify a serious problem.

I usually work with PHP not JS so I'm wondering if there is something simple I am missing here?

```
function validatequestion(form){
        var e = document.getElementById("chooseqtype");
        var strQtype = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        if(strQtype == "default"){
            alert("Please select a question type");
            return false;
        }

        if(strQtype == "textquestion"){
            fail = validatetextq(form.textquestiondesc.value)
            if(fail == "") return true
            else {
                alert(fail);
                return false;
            }
        }

        if(strQtype == "videoquestion"){
            fail = validatevideoq(form.videoquestiondesc.value)
            if(fail == "") return true;
            else {
                alert(fail);
                return false;
            }
        }

        //everything above works, after this point nothing seems to get called
        var a = document.getElementById("chooseatype");
        var strAtype = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;

        if(strAtype == "textanswer"){
            //get the value of the number of text answers select box
            var t = document.getElementById("choosetextnumber");
            //put the value in variable strQtype
            var strTextno = t.options[t.selectedIndex].value;


            if(strTextno == "2tanswers"){
                fail = validatetexta1(form.textanswer1.value)
                fail += validatetexta2(form.textanswer2.value)
                if(fail == "") return true;
                else {
                    alert(fail);
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }   




        }
```

Comment: you're return false from first if..

Comment: NITPICK: Use else if!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Do you mean that it executes one of the first three blocks of code, and then stops? If that's the case, it's because you're returning false in each of them.

Comment: I have am trying to valiadte some text fields, but I use 3 selection menus, so not all fields need validating. Eg, if text question is selected, the text field for creating a text question is presented.

Comment: DiMono, but in cases it returns true it also doesn't execute the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `strQtype` can only be one of the 3 values you are testing for then there is no way you can ever get to the second part of your code because you always return from each of those `if` statements.

EDIT:

What you need to do is **not** `return` when `fail == ""`.  Since you're just returning `true` I assume you don't need to return a value, just verify that the validation was successful.  What you should do then is only test for failure, e.g. `if (! fail=="" )`  (syntax is prob wrong, javascript is not my first lang.)  and in that case do your `alert`.

Or you could always just write 3 different functions, one to test each menu item, which is what I would probably do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem with that approach is the three menus always have to be selected. There is a menu to select what type of question you want to make, a menu to select what type of answer to make and a menu to select how many answers you make.

Comment: Well if that's the case then it's back to my original point that you since you **return** from each of those first 3 `if` statements you are never going to get past them.  You need to save the answer they are selecting for the first menu, i.e. what type of question they want to make, then move on so you can check what type of answer they want.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Implemented as you mentioned in edit and it's now working perfectly.